# BLE WroteCharacteristicValue never calls

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing an iOS application with Xamarin.iOS, but an answer in native iOS would be appreciated as well. My application uses a BLE write characteristic to send messages between devices. My code to create and add the service to the CBPeripheralManager:

```
_cbPeripheralManager.WriteRequestsReceived += WriteRequestReceived; // WriteRequestReceived is never called

// my read characteristic actually works fine
_readCharacteristic = new CBMutableCharacteristic(CBUUID.FromString(MyReadCharacteristicUuid), CBCharacteristicProperties.Read | CBCharacteristicProperties.Notify, null, CBAttributePermissions.Readable);

// but my write characteristic doesn't work when i try to write to it
_writeCharacteristic = new CBMutableCharacteristic(CBUUID.FromString(MyWriteCharacteristicUuid), CBCharacteristicProperties.Write | CBCharacteristicProperties.Notify, null, CBAttributePermissions.Writeable);

_service = new CBMutableService(CBUUID.FromString(MyServiceUuid), true);
_service.Characteristics = new CBCharacteristic[2] { _readCharacteristic, _writeCharacteristic };

_cbPeripheralManager.AddService(_service);
```

And my code to write to the characteristic of the peripheral (not showing the code for device and service/characteristic discovery for simplicity)

```
peripheral.WroteCharacteristicValue += handler; // handler is never called
peripheral.WriteValue(NSData.FromString("hello"), characteristic, CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse);
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: You are writing *without response*.  You need to write *with response* for the handler to be called https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518823-peripheral?language=objc

Comment: My `WriteRequestReceived` handler is never called.

Comment: you should implement the error handler. You will be getting an error because you are performing a write without response but your write characteristic only supports write with response

Comment: It was just that, I had to change `CBCharacteristicProperties.Write` to `CBCharacteristicProperties.WriteWithoutResponse` on both the sending and receiving sides. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. By the way, where is the error handler? I can't see find it

Comment: Actually, I don't think there is one in this case.  I think you just get an error message on the console